# Trained tensorflow model moved to another directory cannot be loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a `tensorflow` model and moved the trained model files to another directory, Now if I try to load the model I get this error

> ValueError: Can't load save_path when it is None.

If I load the model without moving it to another directory it works fine. I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391464/load-tensorflow-model-from-moved-directory) but it didn't work

**Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
tf_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.meta')
tf_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('model'))
```

**Files**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `save_relative_paths` flag

```
tf_saver = tf.train.Saver(save_relative_paths=True)
```